# How to run a terminal command and print the output through java in Mac

Tags: java, ios, macos, udid

I tried below code to get the output of the ran command. But it printing empty.

```
String cmd = "/bin/bash device_id -l";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Could anyone please help me. I have to get the connected iDevice UDID.

Comment: Try 
`String cmd = "device_id -l";`

Comment: That is not working in Mac @jctim

Comment: I don't know what does your command do, but I tried `String cmd = "ps -ef";` and got output in stdout. Maybe your command writes in stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below code I could get the connected device udid.

```
public String deviceUDID() throws IOException{
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/idevice_id -l");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        line = r.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        return line;
    }
```